# Why this function works only for visitors?

Tags: php, wordpress

The following code works fine only for visitors, but if i replaced the `include()` with the `socials-links.php`contents, it works fine for both visitors and users.So, What is the problem with the `include()`.
 Here is the code:

```
function render_social_links() {
$current_post_id=get_the_ID();
$them_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
$featured_image_url = '';
if ( has_post_thumbnail( $current_post_id ) ) {
    $featured_image_id  = get_post_thumbnail_id( $current_post_id );
    $featured_image_url = $featured_image_id ? wp_get_attachment_url( $featured_image_id ) : '';
}
if(is_home() || is_single()){
      if(is_home()){
        $bitlink = $lnk = get_bloginfo('url');
        $bitly = getBitly($bitlink);
        $nam = get_bloginfo('name');
        }
        elseif(is_single($current_post_id)){
            $bitlink = $lnk = get_permalink($current_post_id);
            $bitly = getBitly($bitlink);
            $nam = get_the_title($current_post_id);
        }
        $bitlink =esc_url( $bitlink );
        $lnk = esc_url( $lnk );
        $nam= esc_attr( $nam );
        $bitly = esc_url( $bitly );
        include( $them_uri.'/social-links.php' );
      }

  }
```

Here is the social-links.php contents :

```
<div id="socialleft">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/share-38.png" alt=""/>
       </li>
    <li>
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='.$lnk.'&amp;t='.$nam.'" title="شارك على فيسبوك" target="_blank">
      </li>
             <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/facebook-38.png" alt="" />
           </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status='.$nam.' : '.$bitly.'" title="غرد" target="_blank">
        <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/twitter-38.png" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$lnk.'" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,\'\', \'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=60\');return false;" title="شارك على جوجل+" target="_blank">
 <img src="'.$them_uri.'/images/social/Google-plus-38.png" alt="" />
        </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

And Css related to social_links.php :

```
   #socialleft{
     position:fixed; 
     top: 35%; 
     left: 0; 
     height:100%; 
     width:45px;
     margin-left:15px;
     display:block;
     z-index:100;
     transition: width ease .5s;    
   }
```

Comment: so, where is the problem and what you want now?

Comment: the problem is the Include makes the output available for visitors only, but when me (the admin) or other user logs in, then no output.that is what i am asking, why this happens ?

Comment: please enable debug and check

Comment: Is it complete file??

Comment: yes it is with no php tags

Comment: do you get any error???

Comment: i will check the error log because nothing on the front end

Comment: No Errors Found  :(

Comment: WP_DEBUG in wp-config

Comment: I will try WP_DEBUG

Comment: @MohamedOmar Its hack you have to manage your self after this : 
add css into your file.inside <style> <!-- You Css --> </style>

Comment: Ok, I will . Thanks a lot for your concern

Answer (score 0):

In this case there is a condition in included file for admin

```
include( $them_uri.'/social-links.php' );
```

You code is warped inside a conditional tag.

```
if (!is_admin()):

end if;
```

Comment: the file exists inside the child theme that is why i am using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();`. and it already loads but only for visitors not logged in users

Comment: share file social-links.php

Comment: Not warped inside a conditional tag . because if it is , so at least it should work for admin. but it works only for visitors

Comment: It means there is css that `display:none` make share div hidden.

Comment: Isn't the CSS apply for any user?, I know so , but it shows for visitors only

Comment: Please add div in starting of file (social)and add something to it.check is it visible?

Comment: i added as you said and it is visible

Comment: I will add the css to the question

Comment: please add css in question.In console check all css files load that acutlly load in frontend and same load in admin.

Comment: I tried to remove the `id=socialleft` and reloaded the page nothing changes at all. i doubt that the problem is that the file contains variables.